# FormsAuthentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a large ASP.NET MVC 5 application that I am porting to ASP.NET Core. Porting is planned to be done a few routes at a time, since it’s pretty large.

So, this means when a user logs into my new .NET Core app, I have to also log them into the old .NET Framework app.

The old app is using **FormsAuthentication** to authorize. So the plan is that if I create a cookie in my new app that the old app’s FormsAuthentication understands then I will be set.

But since Core doesn’t support FormsAuthentication, I cannot do this.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You do know that you can run ASP.NET Core 2.x _on_ .NET Framework 4.8, right? So to port an ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET Core you don't need to run them side-by-side: you can do it in-place.

Comment: In which version of asp.net core you would like to upgrade into as Dai said you can use 2.XX simultaneously so have you tried that?

Comment: Porting to Core 6, running it in a Linux container, so has to be side by side.